# Jest mock class method on a test-by-test basis

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to mock out a utility library class with a method that returns a JSON.

Actual library structure

```
module.exports = class Common() {
  getConfig() {
  return {
    real: 'data'
  }
}
```

The file under test looks like:

```
const Common = require('./common');
const common = new Common();
const config = common.getConfig();

...

const someFunction = function() {
  // config.real is used inside this function
}
```

I'm trying to mock out the Common class and return a different config JSON for each Jest test.

```
const fileUnderTest = require('./../fileUnderTest.js');
const Common = require('./../common.js');
jest.mock('./../common.js');

describe('something', () => {
  it('test one', () => {
    Common.getConfig = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        real : 'fake' // This should be returned for test one
      };
    });

    fileUnderTest.someFunction(); //config.real is undefined at this point
  });

  it('test two', () => {
  Common.getConfig = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        real : 'fake2' // This should be returned for test two
      };
    });
  })
})
```

Is it possible to set the return value from the mock class method created by the automock of `common.js` at the top of the test file?

I've tried to use `mockReturnValueOnce()` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`jest.mock`**

In this case you don't really need to auto-mock the entire `common` module since you are just replacing the implementation of one method so `jest.mock('./../common');` isn't necessary.

**`Common.getConfig`**

`getConfig` is a [prototype method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods) so `getConfig` exists on the *prototype* of `Common`.  To mock it use `Common.prototype.getConfig` instead of `Common.getConfig`.

**`config in fileUnderTest.js`**

An instance of `Common` gets created and `config` gets set to the result of calling `common.getConfig()` *as soon as `fileUnderTest` runs*, which happens *as soon as it gets required* so the mock for `Common.prototype.getConfig` has to be in place *before* you call `require('./../fileUnderTest')`.

---

```
const Common = require('./../common');
Common.prototype.getConfig = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ real: 'fake' }));
const fileUnderTest = require('./../fileUnderTest');

describe('something', () => {
  it('should test something', () => {
    fileUnderTest.someFunction();  // config.real is 'fake' at this point
  });
});
```

---

**Update**

To mock `config.real` differently *for each test* for code like this requires that the [modules be reset](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestresetmodules) between tests:

```
describe('something', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();  // reset modules after each test
  })

  it('test one', () => {
    const Common = require('./../common');
    Common.prototype.getConfig = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ real: 'fake' }));
    const fileUnderTest = require('./../fileUnderTest');
    fileUnderTest.someFunction();  // config.real is 'fake'
  });

  it('test two', () => {
    const Common = require('./../common');    
    Common.prototype.getConfig = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({ real: 'fake2' }));
    const fileUnderTest = require('./../fileUnderTest');
    fileUnderTest.someFunction();  // config.real is 'fake2'
  })
})
```

Resetting the modules is necessary because once a module is required it is added to the module cache and that same module gets returned each time it is required unless the modules are reset.

Comment: I think I was unclear with the question, sorry. I need to return something different from the prototype method for each `it`. I've edited the question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I think Jest requires a small reset of thinking at times to contain all the needed requires, etc. inside the it block! Feels a bit clunky for the moment, though.